# How to update Android version 2.3.6

Tags: android

I am using eclipse and installed android sdk which contains android 2.3.3 version but I want update my sdk and download android 2.3.6 version. 
When I am go through AVD SDK Manager and check available package but it doesn't show  the package of android version 2.3.6

How to update android version in 2.3.6 because I want create android emulator 2.3.6 for installing development.apk  on my nexus devices for debugging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this update is released for nexus devices & its same as api level 2.3.3

Answer (score 7):

There is no change in Api level from 2.3.3 to 2.3.6. So for an app developer it does not matter whether you are running app on 2.3.3 device or a 2.3.6 device. So google does not give a separate emulator for 2.3.6

Comment: Unfortunately, this is only true in theory. In practice, [apps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.iglulabs.medine) that work fine on the rest of 2.3.x and 4.x devices, seem to fail on 2.3.5 and 2.3.6 (GT-S5830i) devices. So far it seems there is no way to emulate them and the only way is to test on actual devices. Please do let me know if there is.

Answer (score 5):

unfortunately, 2.3.6 has many bug fixes which mean that things that might work/fail on 2.3.6 fail/work on 2.3.3.

Answer (score 3):

According to the information provided in the official website, 2.3.6 version is the same as 2.3.3 (from the perspective of application development):

> Gingerbread   2.3.3 - 2.3.7   API level 10

However, you have the source code tags (e.g. `android-2.3.6_r0.9`) that you can use to download the sources for your devices.

More information can be found here: [Codenames, Tags, and Build Numbers](http://source.android.com/source/build-numbers.html)

Answer (score 2):

The android SDK 2.3.3 supports all versions from 2.3.3-2.3.7

No need to update the SDK

Answer (score 1):

The Android Versions Official in Emulator :

Android 3.2 
Android 3.1 
Android 3.0 
Android 2.3.4 
Android 2.3.3 
Android 2.2 
Android 2.1

so 2.3.6 will be the same as 2.3.4